# Replacing multiple characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function where the parameter is a string and a specific character needs to be replaced. It will then give an alert box with the converted string.

I have the following code but it isn't working. I also want it to `alert()` the converted string.

```
function encryption(aString){
    return aString.replace(/a/g, '@')
      .replace(/e/g, '()')
      .replace(/h/g, '#')
      .replace(/l/g,'1')
      .replace(/r/g,'+')
      .replace(/s/g.'$')
      .replace(/v/g,'^')
      .replace(/x/g,'*');
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? The typo should have caused a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight I see a typo here

```
.replace(/s/g.'$')
```

It should be

```
.replace(/s/g,'$')
```

You can see it working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7takvc0/) after fixing the typo

Comment: Nice eye! Thank you! When I run it through my webpage nothing happens though even after I fix the edit? `function encryption(aString){
       return aString.replace(/a/g, '@').replace(/e/g, '()').replace(/h/g, '#').replace(/l/g,'1').replace(/r/g,'+').replace(/s/g,'$').replace(/v/g,'^').replace(/x/g,'*');
     alert(aString);}`

Comment: @Robben The `alert()` after `return ...` will not get executed.

Comment: @Robben - `aString` is _not_ modified when passed to `encryption()` - you want to alert the _return value_ of the function call, not the original string: `alert(encryption(aString))` as is done in Claudio's fiddle.

Comment: @Ja͢ck  Will I then have to replace the `return` with `alert()`?

Comment: @Robben The fiddle in this answer works, so if anything, just copy that. If you don't understand how JavaScript works, please read up on it [here](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript).

Comment: I got it to work! I wrapped with `alert` instead of `return`.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Robben instead of removing the return from your function rather do like: `alert( encryption("hello world") );`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

```
.replace(/s/g.'$')
```

The period should be a comma, and the `$` character is used for replacements code in the replacement string, so you have to escape it as `$$`:

```
.replace(/s/g, '$$')
```

---

You can use a single replace instead of chaining all those replaces:

```js
function encryption(aString){
  return aString.replace(/[aehlrsvx]/g, function (m) {
    return m == 'e' ? '()' : '@#1+$^*'['ahlrsvx'.indexOf(m)];
  });
}

// display result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(encryption('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.'));
```

Comment: There's no need to escape `'$'` if it's the only character in the replacement string; at least, that's what Safari seems to suggest.

Comment: Also Robben, the whole script could be even simpler if you only used one character to replace `e`